# Typeorm is not saving data in table. How to do Migrations in typeorm?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I have this mutation

```
@Mutation(() => AuthResponse, { nullable: true })
  async signUp(
    @Ctx() { req }: MyContext,
    @Arg("details") details: UsernamePasswordTypes
  ): Promise<AuthResponse> {
    const { password, username } = details;
    const user = await User.create({
      username,
      password: "hasedPassword"
    });
    
    try {
      await user.save();
      req.session.userId = user.id;
      console.log("USER CREATED",user)
      return {user}
    } catch (e) {
      return {
        errors: [
          {
            field: "username",
            message: "username already taken",
          },
        ],
      };
    }
  }
```

In this i can see `USER created`

I have 2 problems

- It is not printing password field in console
- It is not saving data in postgres db but it have created user table

**Note** : I am running this code for first time so i think i need to create table and fields so dont know how to. How to create migrations in typeorm ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to create migrations using TypeOrm.

There are two methods you must fill with your migration code: up and down. up has to contain the code you need to perform the migration. down has to revert whatever up changed. down method is used to revert the last migration.

You can manually create them using `typeorm migration:create -n migrationName` adding your `up` and `down` instructions:

```js
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from 'typeorm';

export class PostRefactoringTIMESTAMP implements MigrationInterface {

    async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TABLE "users" ("create_date" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), "update_date" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), "delete_date" TIMESTAMP, "id" SERIAL NOT NULL, "firstName" character varying NOT NULL, "lastName" character varying NOT NULL, "email" character varying NOT NULL, "phone" character varying, "password" character varying NOT NULL)`);
    }

    async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE "users"`);
    }
}
```

Else, you can generate them from your entities using `typeorm migration:generate -n generatedMigrationName`.

When your migrations are done, you can run them with `typeorm migration:run` and `typeorm migration:revert` to use the down method.

Don't forget to setup your connection options properly:

```js
{
    "type": "mysql",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "username": "test",
    "password": "test",
    "database": "test",
    "entities": ["entity/*.js"],
    "migrationsTableName": "custom_migration_table",
    "migrations": ["migration/*.js"],
    "cli": {
        "migrationsDir": "migration"
    }
}
```

If you have more questions, mind reading the [TypeOrm documentation about migrations](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/migrations.md)

Comment: Do i have to write sql for creating tables after defining entity ?

Comment: No, you can avoid writing SQL by generating the migration using `typeorm migration:generate`. If you want to write it manually without SQL, you can use the [TypeOrm migration API](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/migrations.md#using-migration-api-to-write-migrations)